# Why am I getting very very rough accelerometer measurements in PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am building a simple accelerometer app in PhoneGap primarily targeted to Android, and depending on what I set the frequency to, I get very inconsistent readings. If I set the frequency to 100, I get 10 measurements a second. However if I try something like frequency of 50ms or 40 or 10, I get very inconsistent readings of anything from 18 to 27 readings a second.

Comment: Built it natively.. Phonegap is buggy.

Comment: @JakeWilson801 natively is too hard :C besides it's too late to redo it, have to submit next week. I mean are you sure it's the fact that phonegap is buggy? it gets some pretty awesome reviews?

Comment: I'd say that if you need to use specialized hardware, PhoneGap is not the way to go.

Comment: Well, accelerometer is fairly standard hardware and PhoneGap claims to have full support for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it comes down to the fact that setInterval is not guaranteed to fire at the interval that you provide. Since JavaScript is single threaded it may be busy doing something else when the interval time is reached. This would account for the variable readings you are getting.